# Specify number of decimals in crystal reports chart axis

Tags: crystal-reports, charts, formatting, crystal-reports-xi, axis-labels

Am I just blind or is this basic feature very hidden?

I'm creating a chart in Crystal Reports XI which has value on the x-axis and distinct count on y-axis (aka histogram).

The problem is this: I get two decimal places on the x-axis values even though the numbers are integers. How can I specify the number of decimals for the x-axis? Right clicking gives no format option as right clicking data fields usually does.

Edit:

This is the look of the axis tab in the chart expert. No number format or auto range for the x axis.

[image: Axis tab of Crystal Reports chart expert.]

Answer (score 0):

It may have changed as i'm on the latest version of Crystal. Does yours not look like this?

[image]

Comment: No, I don't have the number tab.
After a quick further investigation I see that I have the number tab on the y-axis... Strange.

Answer (score 0):

In crystal Xi , chart expert , tab axes, untick auto range, and choose number format 
(screenshot refused to new users, sorry mate)

Hope this helps

Comment: There I have options for the y-axis, but not the x-axis. See added screenshot in edited post.

Answer (score 0):

For Crystal report 13 write the crystal report formula

```
ToText({fieldname}, 0, "")
```

`0` truncates the decimal, and `""` removes the thousands separator.

Comment: We're getting close to a workaround, but that gives me the following order on the x-axis:
0 100 125 150 175 200 225 25 250 275 300 325 50 75